# Python null (Undefined) check best approach

Tags: python, class

Best approach to check null (undefined) instances before executing other routines?

I keep getting a name error that I do not know how to fix it, I clearly defined it in my code so I do not understand

[screenshot of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ufsC.png)

Comment: Method call is written `customer.loanvideo(x)` and not `loanvideo(self, x)`, but you'll first need a customer object.

Comment: Prefer to include code as text in the question rather than as an image. Also, the name error is `loanvideo` and not `loanedvideos` right?

Answer (score 0):

You need to instantiate the `customers` object first, but even once you've done that you still need to select a customer and a video:

```
...

elif choice== 2:
    c = customers(<name>) # you haven't assigned a name so add this in
    loanedvideo = c.loanvideo(x) # You also need to define which video here
```

The `self` is not required as this is a reference to the customer instance itself and can only be referenced from within the class to access attributes or methods of the class.